# Filtering function issues in BS4 find_all() statement in Python

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup, tags, filtering

I'm scraping an HTML webpage. I'm using the BeautifulSoup lib (4.6.0) and Python (3.7) on a Mac (Sierra).

Among other things, I see a bunch of 'div' tags which have class attributes. Some of the 'div' tags come with multiple class attribute values. Now I want to filter based on tag name and class attribute values, e.g. I want to find the 'div' tags that have class='a' but not class='b' (and, yes, some of the div tags come with class='a b').

To get those tags I tried to use a filtering function as mention in the BS4 documentation (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function). I'm under the impression that find_all() passes a bs4 tag element to the function and within the function you can do whatever you would do on a BS4 tag element. That seems not to be true. I get a string and obviously all my BS4 tag element operations raise an exception.

Two questions:

1. What exactly does find_all() pass to the function and how can the argument be used?
2. Besides a function how would otherwise be able to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Including a snippet of your html and other code to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help us understand your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm under the impression that find_all() passes a bs4 tag element to the function and within the function you can do whatever you would do on a BS4 tag element.

Your impression is correct. From the bs4 documentation (emphasis mine):

> ... define a function that **takes an element** as its only argument.

So each element in the document is passed to the filter function, and if the function returns `True` for that element, it's included in the returned list of elements from `.find_all()`. This should really only be used as a last resort as it can be pretty performance intensive. I'm not entirely sure why you're getting strings, one possibility is that you're passing the function to the `class_=` param, which does pass in strings, but can't say without seeing your code.

I think what you should do is use `.find_all()` to get all `<div>`s with class "a", and then filter those to only include those that don't have class "b" using your own methods, something like this:

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='a')
filtered_divs = [ div for div in divs if 'b' not in div.attrs['class'].split(' ') ]
```

But if you did want to use the filter function, it'd look something like

```
class_a_not_b(e):
    if 'class' not in e.attrs: return False
    return 'a' in e.attrs['class'].split(' ') and 'b' not in e.attrs['class'].split(' ')

divs = soup.find_all(class_a_not_b)
```